# Impala query using Airflow

Tags: python, airflow, cloudera, impala

Is it possible to use one of airflow's operators to run an Impala query in the same way it can do Hive queries? I imagine a bash operator will work but would like do do it using the airflow api.

Comment: Have you check this one out https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_api/airflow/hooks/hive_hooks/index.html#airflow.hooks.hive_hooks.HiveServer2Hook
if you are using impala you may need to set it to false in the extra of your connection in the UI

Comment: Do you have an example? It doesn't mention Impala.

Answer (score 1):

To connect impala from airflow, we need to mention authentication type and run_set_variable_statements in extra column in connection.

To connect with no authentication mechanism, below are the connection details.
**Connection Type :** Hive Server 2 Thrift
**Port :** 21050
**Schema:** Your Database
**Extra:** {"authMechanism": "NOSASL", "run_set_variable_statements":false}

Answer (score 0):

I made it as a jdbc connection. This is the way I set up the configuration:

- Connection Id: the_id_you_want
- Connection Type: JDBC Connection
- Connection URL: jdbc:impala://the_url_worker.root.corp:21050
- Login: my_username
- Password: my_password
- Driver Path: url where the .jar file locates
- Driver Class: com.cloudera.impala.jdbc.Driver

Edit: this is for Airflow v2.6.0